# Send email to shared contacts group

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

My collegue's shared a contact group with me so I can cover one of his jobs whilst he's on leave. I need to send an email to the people in this group. How can I do this? I can see the group and its members here but nothing I can see lets me send an email to them:

[image]

I've tried moving and copying the group into my Contacts folder, but always get one of the following two errors:

> The attempted operation failed. An object could not be bound.

or

> You do not have permissions to move items in this folder. To check your permissions ... etc

When creating a new email, the shared group does not seem to appear anywhere in the address book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the **"Current View"** in the Outlook ribbon. 
Your picture shows you are in **People** view. Change **People** view to **List** view and the **Communicate** section will expand to include an **E-mail button**. That E-mail button will let you compose an e-mail to any highlight people at once, with a single click.
Thanks for including the pic--it made it easy to see what was going on! :)